# loop throught a function properties, possible?

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through a functions properties, here is my attempt:

```js
var hen = function a() {
  this.name = "euler henrique";
  this.ID = 55530;
  this.REC = 0302;
  this.nick = "any will do";
}

for (var p in hen) {
  console.log(hen[p]);
}
```

but that doesn't work, even if `hen` was an instance of `a`. Any suggestion?

Comment: `hen` is a constructor. use it as such. `var p in new hen`

Comment: What would you do with the properties of the function? Most of them are not very useful outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution might be to add the elements to an array, as a property of the parent object. For instance

```
var hen = function a() {
  this.name = "euler henrique";
  this.ID = 55530;
  this.REC = 0302;
  this.nick = "any will do";

  this.info = [this.name, this.id, this.REC, this.nick];
}
```

And then looping through this array the way you would any array.

```
var myHen = new Hen();
for(var x = 0; x < myHen.info; x ++)
{
  info = myHen.info[x];

  if(info)
  {
    console.log(info);
  }
}
```

Not sure if this what you were going for, let me know if this isn't what you need and i'd be happy to share some other ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it if you create an instance of the object:

```js
var Hen = function() {
  this.name = "euler henrique";
  this.ID = 55530;
  this.REC = 0302;
  this.nick = "any will do";
}

var myHen = new Hen();
for (let prop in myHen) {
  if (myHen.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
```

You can create an object using the **function constructor**: `new YourFunctionName();`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty): "The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it)."

Comment: `function` do have properties. it's just another object

Comment: In addition to what adelin said I think you should recommend checking `myHen.hasOwnProperty(prop)`

Comment: what is the mechanism behind it? I mean when an instance is created javascript generate an array with it properties and methods? why alert(myhen[1]) doen't work then?

Comment: When you use the function constructor, it returns an object, not an array. You should use the key, not an index, like `myHen.name`

Comment: @henricoo, check this doc: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

Comment: so the key word "in" in javascript as in "for(prop in myHen)" read object properties directly? is that what this key word made for?

Comment: That's a for... in loop, it allows you iterate over the keys of an object

Comment: that is exactly my point i mean if objects have index shouldn't i be able to do that: alert(myHen[1]); ?? even outside of for(){} scope

Comment: No, you are not iterating using the index, you are iterating over the enumerable properties of an object. You can use the index to access arrays, but you need to use keys to access objects

Comment: Damian Peralta, now it made sense to me and i can give it a rest to the restlessness in mind. thank you